# msmtp not working?

Tags: email, smtp

I was trying to send an e-mail from the terminal, but it doesn't work and I can't find the reason. My `.msmtprc` file is:

```
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
from account@gmail.com
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
auth on
user account@gmail.com
password password
logfile ~/.msmtp
```

(instead of account and password, of course, I have my data written)
Then I use command

```
msmtp -t < test.txt
```

and no mail is sent (`test.txt` contains To:, From:, Subject: and text)!

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Do you use 2 step authorization with gmail?

Comment: Do you have sendmail installed? are you looking to receive messages as well?

Comment: seems as if you miss out which account msmtp should use with `msmtp -a default -t < test.txt`  the acount name is "default" but it was not configured as default account with `account default : default` within the configuration file